# El @Html.TextBox no me ocupa todo el ancho adentro de un <div>

Tags: css, mvc

Mi `@Html.TextBox` esta adentro de un `<div class="input-group">` pero me ocupa solo una parte en cuanto al ancho del `<div>`, y ademas el icono de la lupa para hacer la búsqueda esta muy separada, mi idea es que el ancho del `@Html.TextBox` llegue hasta el icono de la lupa, que queden pegados. Intente establecerle a mi `@Html.TextBox`el ancho en porcentaje con CSS, pero no pasa nada, lo ignora. De que forma se puede solucionar?.

Aca en el .cshtml

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Libros", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBox("searching", "", new { @class = "form-control", id = "txt_search", placeholder = "Ingrese nombre del libro" })
             <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="search">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="iconLupa"></i></button>
             </div>
        </div>   
}
```

Aca mi CSS

```
#txt_search{
width: 100%;
```

}

Aca muestro la imagen de lo que sucede:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente agregando `<div class="input-group-prepend">` pero tampoco, aca el codigo cuando inspecciono el elemento (Estoy usando la version Bootstrap v3.3.7):

```html
<form action="/Home/Libros" method="post">    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="txt_search" name="searching" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del libro" type="text" value="">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="search">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" id="iconLupa"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Estas trabajando con un proyecto estándar creado con Visual Studio?

Comment: si con visual studio 2017!

Comment: Todo este formulario esta adentro de <div class="container body-content"> por ahí existe alguna propiedad en ese div que no me este permitiendo el ancho del textBox?

Comment: En tu primera versión cambia el div por span en el input-group-btn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO! no se porque razón no se me actualizaban los cambios. La solución fue poner un `id = "txtBuscar"` al `@Html.TextBox` para después darle el ancho con una hoja de estilos `CSS` creada por mi. También se ajusta perfectamente a los diferentes tamaños de pantalla aca `.cshtml`:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Libros", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   
      <div class="input-group">
          @Html.TextBox("searching", "", new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtBuscar", placeholder = "Ingrese nombre del libro", maxlength = "80" })
          <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
}
```

y en el `CSS` escribir `!important`:

```
#txtBuscar {
max-width: 100% !important;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Esto es debido a que se generan dos contenedores para tus elementos `<div class="form-control">` y el `<div class="input-group-btn">`, debes reemplezar `input-group-btn` por `input-group-append`.

## Botstrap 4. input-group

Esta clase permite generar un grupo de elementos junto a un input, permitiendo agrupar otros elementos antes del input con `input-group-prepend` o después del elemento con `input-group-append`, asi los elementos que agregues dentro de estos contenedores quedaran a la derecha o izquierda del tu input.

> Para que funciones correctamente el  `input-group-prepend` se declara antes del `form-control` y el `input-group-append` despues del `form-control`

## Botstrap 3. input-group

Esta clase permite generar un grupo de elementos junto a un input, permitiendo agrupar otros elementos al input con `input-group-btn`, si declara se antes del `form-control` quedaran agrupados a la izquierda y si declara después del `form-control` quedaran agrupados a la derecha.

```html
<!-- cargar bootstrap y fas icons -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


<body>
<!-- derecha -->
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe aqui">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
        <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Buscar</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- izquierda -->
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
          <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true">        </i>Buscar</button>
    </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe aqui">
  
</div>

<!-- dentro de formulario -->
<form action="/Home/Libros" method="post">   
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="txt_search" name="searching" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del libro" type="text" value="">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" id="iconLupa"></i>
      </button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias @Diego Mesa por responder!, pero sigue sin funcionar, es mas poniendo lo que acabas de compartir el icono de la lupa se sitúa abajo del textbox, y el textbox sigue sin ocuparme el ancho

Comment: Puede actualizar la pregunta, agregando la salida del HTML que generar en el navegador ( si es chrome `click derecho > inspeccionar elemento` )  para conocer la estructura real del html generado por el helper.

Comment: Ademas que versión de bootstrap estas usando ?

Comment: Estoy usando la version  Bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment: En tu primera versión cambia el div por span en el input-group-btn

Comment: @Claudio he actualizado la respuesta usando Bootstrap v3.3.7 , si siguen sin funcionar probablemente es que tienes cambios en tu css que alteran el comportamiento de estas clases.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontré a este problema fue poner la propiedad **display:block** al `<div class="input-group">` acá el código cshtml:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Libros", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
          {
              <div class="input-group" style="display:block">
                 
                      @Html.TextBox("searching", "", new { @class = "form-control", id = "txt_search", placeholder = "Ingrese nombre del libro" })
                  
                      <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn_search" type="submit" value="search">
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" id="iconLupa"></i>
                      </button>
                 
              </div>
          }
```

Y después cree un estilo CSS donde establecí el ancho del @Html.TextBox y un ancho para el botón de búsqueda.

Aca el CSS

```css
#txt_search{ 
    max-width: 95% !important;
}

#btn_search{
    max-width: 5% !important;
}
```

El único problema o defecto que hay es que por ejemplo si achico la pantalla del navegador a una resolución de 375 x 667 (tamaño de iphone 6) el icono de la lupa se sitúa abajo del textBox en ves de quedarme al lado.

Answer (score 0):

Vi que solucionaste tu problema pero podrías revisar esta opción:
Dentro del archivo Site.css que viene por defecto en MVC, hay un estilo para los input, select y textarea que les formatea un width. Es exactamente esta parte del codigo de la hoja de estilos

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Fijate si le sacas eso, o si le pones

> max-width: 100%

Comment: Gracias @iMSn20 por responder!. Si, ya me habían dicho que haga eso pero no me había funcionado tampoco, sin embargo ahora volví a hacerlo como vos dijiste ahí en Site.css puse max-width: 100% y borre los estilos que había puesto en mi .css y me funciona perfecto, lo cual me llama la atención por qué razón antes no me actualizaba los cambios cuando los editaba desde el Site.css.

Comment: @Claudio si ves que haces un cambio y no se te actualiza agrega **!important** luego de la propiedad. Ejemplo: 
`max-width: 100% !important` 
Y fijate si asi funciona. Aveces un estilo en otra hoja u otro lado sobreescribe al que estas queriendo agregar.

Comment: Si eso había hecho! gracias por responder!